# How to detect call status in Android

Tags: android, kotlin

How can I check if there is an ongoing call or not with `TelephonyManager`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a very broad question. I suggest you read [Build a calling app](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/telecom/selfManaged). Then you can provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @ChristianB how is "check if there is an ongoing call or not" "very broad"?

Comment: @Ryan M it was just my opinion. Maybe it's not. Usually I like to see people do some coding first and then come with a concrete sample + question. Cause you never know what is the current status. In this context I meant it's broad.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     call.registerCallback(object : Call.Callback() {
            override fun onStateChanged(call: Call?, state: Int) {
                super.onStateChanged(call, state)
                     if(call?.state == Call.STATE_ACTIVE){
                    //todo
                }
            }
        })
```

Comment: How can I get call object. Currently can't access call object. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to Implement

'import android.telecom.InCallService'

and method 
'onCallAdded(call:Call)'